# How can i disable input textfield from user with only One-Time-Code auto fill support

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I want to disable manual text entering from one-time-code textField while the user only can tap SMS OTP Code from Keyboard Quicktype Bar.

Another question i got from seeing whatsapp is that their input shows the Keyboard Quicktype bar automatically while mine is not unless i call `becomeFirstResponder`

How can i achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are trying to disable user interaction, you could add `textField.isEnabled = false` but you can still populate the text programmatically with some logic within your program

Comment: @ShawnFrank i've tried `isEnabled=false`, then the keyboard won't appear.

Comment: So if the user types something from the keyboard, you want these characters to be ignored and not appear in the textfield ?

Comment: Yes and at the same time, the keyboard to appear automatically for incoming otp code.

Comment: @abdullahicyc, did you managed to find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, maybe it works for your use case

Remove `textField.isEnabled = false` if you added it before

Add `textField.delegate = self` so we can manage what happens when user adds input

Add `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` to make the keyboard appear

Then implement this UITextFieldDelegate callback

```
extension YourViewOrViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
                   shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                   replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        // Only allow multiple characters to be set like the OTP
        // Or define your own logic when you want text to be
        // accepted into the text field
        return string.count != 1
    }
}
```

Check if this gives you the desired result